# Go/goland can't read repositories

Tags: go, goland

I'm currently working in Go to make some microservices, using go get works perfectly fine to install the packages required however it does not find them in my IDE (Goland by Jetbrains) they show up in the editor like this

[image: imports]

when using the macro in Goland to it provides the option to run the go get command, when running that command the terminal shows this error

[image]

I did some searching and couldn't find much on it, one thing I saw people saying was for the github import that it couldn't find my SSH key on Github, I've checked and re-added my SSH key to Github and it's working as intended. Should also mention that the repo in the import is private.

Comment: What's the error that you receive? Also, where does the GOPATH points to? Go to Settings/Preferences | Go | GOPATH and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: My mistake added the wrong picture, I've edited the original thread to include the correct error. As for the GOPATH It's set to C:\Users\George\go

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is to replace `github.com` url with the ssh one so instead of:

```
...
pb "github.com:/eros/Micro/proto/consignment"
...
```

try to use:

```
...
pb "git@github.com:/eros/Micro/proto/consignment"
...
```

If that doesn't work I would open terminal in Goland (`ALT/OPTION) + F12`) and try to execute the same go get command that breaks. If it fails the same way - great! Now just go and see what is different than executing it outside Goland (what are env vars, which ssh key Goland terminal is using, etc.)